# Meaning of もんじゃない

Tags: grammar

What does this mean?
すてき！！こういうこせい的などくそう的なまちがいはだれにもやれる**もんじゃない**わ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's short for ものじゃない.

> すてき！！こういうこせい的などくそう的なまちがいはだれにもやれる**もんじゃない**わ 
> Awesome!! This kind of unique, stupid mistake is **not** some**thing** anyone can do!